# reading Image fails: Java

Tags: java, image, canvas

Im coding a liitle game for java and want to make the Player look like a rocket, so i try to load the miage and then draw it on Java awt canvas.
Unfortunately i kepp gettin an IOException, but i dont get why... is the image some how wrong?
Thank you ver helpiNg me in advance and here`s the code:
(the image is in the same package as the Player class)

```
public class Player extends GameEntity {

    private BufferedImage img;

    public Player(int x, int y, ID id){
        super(x, y , id);
    }

     BufferedImage loadImage(String fileName) {
        BufferedImage bi = null;
        //System.err.println("....setimg...." + fileName);

        try {
            bi = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Image could not be read");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        return bi;
    }

    @Override
    public void tick() {
        x += velX;
        y += velY;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(Graphics graphics) {
        AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
        BufferedImage rocketImage = loadImage("rocket.png");

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) graphics;
        g2d.drawImage(rocketImage, at, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly does the IOException say?

Comment: it says cant read input file